# Fixing wrong branch creation in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I recently inherited a project that used Perforce for version control.
Although the product has many versions the branches were done in a copy-paste style.

The result is that I can't view a file history or use time lapse view.

Is there any way to retroactively bind separated branches and tell perforce that branch 2.x was branch from 1.x ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar situation once before, and what I did was integrate from branch 1.x to branch 2.x, but then do "accept target" when resolving all the files. Not sure if that will get you exactly what you're looking for, but it will at least establish integration history if there are ever future updates to the 1.x branch that you'd like to integrate to 2.x.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will give it a go and will update if it's good enough for me.

Comment: Hi Mike, After consulting with additional people we think that the solution above will not allow really see a revision graph or time-lapse view. Can you confirm that it worked for you. If you use P4V can you time-lapse a new file and see old revisions via time-lapse?